# Is $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{2^p}$ irrational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, pigeonhole-principle, rationality-testing

$$ \sum_{p \, \in \text{ primes}} \frac{1}{2^p} $$

My friend came across a book which claimed this to be irrational and claimed it could be solved using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Well, the pigeonhole principle is used to prove that any rational number, when written in any base $b$, either terminates or repeats. This number, when written in base $2,$ does not terminate nor repeat.

Comment: Dear Agnishom. You should first check the related questions (right margin), before posing a question.

Comment: What do you think about the number $0.011010100010100010100010000010_2\cdots$ ?